# Does a public key need to be saved on every client that wants access?

Tags: server, ssh

If I create an SSH key pair, will I only be able to login through a client machine that has the public key? For example, if I wanted to use a computer at the library or a friend's machine would I be able to?

Part 2:
Is it possible to enable password authentication and a SSH key but only use one to login? Will this defeat the purpose of having a key?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you configure your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. If you still allow logins with just password authentication, you won't need the keys on every computer you want to log in with.

The following line in that file will stop any regular password logins:

```
PasswordAuthentication  no
```

This line is set to yes by default.

You can create an ssh key-pair with no associated passphrase (leave blank in the generation process), then the username supplying the correct public key will be able to log in with no password, but your password logins will still work.

You're not defeating the purpose of having a key by allowing password login, but you are leaving more options for an attacker, such as brute-forcing your password. If you use a strong password, and a non-standard username (not root, admin or user), you will lessen this risk.

I'm a big fan of not having port 22 open on the router which your PC sits behind, but port forwarding or NAT-ing a non-standard port to your PCs ssh port. Then when you log in you'd use:

```
ssh -p<port-number> user@ip_address
```

[Here's](http://thepcspy.com/read/making-ssh-secure/) a good link about ssh-hardening, if you're going to have your port open to the world!

Answer (score 0):

You need access to the private key with each client you wish to use for ssh access.

Personally I use PuTTY on a flash drive as Putty is cross platform. You will need to import the openssh keys to PuTTY keygen.

http://www.putty.org/

You can access ssh without keys (password, kerberos, host based auth) as an alternate.

So if you are using keys, ssh will attempt to use a key first. If a key is not available it will fall back to password authentication unless you have disabled password authentication in sshd_config.

If you make a key, you can still log in with passwords or any other method.

log in is configured via sshd_config - See man sshd - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring